# При команде миграции ничего не происходит, что не так?

Tags: django, hosting

Я на хостинге добавил в модель функцию unicode

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='Логин', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', upload_to='kinomonster/media/avatars')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name.username}'

    def unicode(self):
        return u'%s' % (value)
```

После этого я активировал вирт.среду и в putty произвел миграцию

```
./manage.py migrate
```

В ответ мне ничего не пришло и изменений не было.
Как произвести миграцию?

**спасибо**

Comment: Структура бд не поменялась, все нормально. А что ожидалось?

Comment: Разве не должен придти ответ, что нечего добавлять? Putty секунду потупил и ничего не выдал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы добавляете какие-то функции/методы в модель - миграции делать не нужно, они сразу будут работать. Миграции делать нужно когда вы добавляете какую-то модель или меняете её поля(или создаёте поля модели)

Comment: Что-то я протупил, спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста! : )